# How / Where to download Pylab for Python 2.7 on Win32?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have googled all over, and don't see where to get pylab.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe there are two "versions" of pylab floating around/being referred to.

The first is a part of `matplotlib` -- you just [install matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html) and do either `import pylab` or `import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot`. (More info on [pylab vs pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11469336/646543)).

The second is described [here](http://www.scipy.org/PyLab), and as far as I know, doesn't exist yet. The linked version is simply describing a hypothetical vision of what the existing version of pylab could be. It's also unfortunately the first result when you try googling "pylab", which I suspect is what caused your confusion.

Source: http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/pylab-td23420.html#a23423

Comment: Wow, thanks a ton. I looked _everywhere_ and could not find anything that said what you said....

Comment: The link to the forum post was under the first paragraph on this page: http://www.scipy.org/PyLab
:)

Comment: You are right. I did see that page, and did not digest this line " the existing pylab package which is part of matplotlib:"

Answer (score 1):

You can get it as part of [EPD's Canopy distribution](https://www.enthought.com/products/epd/free/).

Comment: As far as I can tell, installing it from Canopy only makes it available from their IDE tool. python 2.7 or Active-State IDE still do not find it.