# Python Pylab, how to alter the size of the label specifying the magnitude of the axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, axis, magnitude

I am attempting to plot differential cross-sections of nuclear decays and so the magnitudes of the y-axis are around `10^-38 (m^2)` pylab as default plots the axis as `0.0,0.2,0.4...` etc and has a `'1e-38'` at the top of the y-axis.

I need to increase the font size of just this little bit, I have tried adjusting the label size

```
py.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=20)
```

but this only adjusts the labels `0.0,0.2,0.4....`

Many thanks for all help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the text object using the [`ax.yaxis.get_offset_text()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis.get_offset_text).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate some data
N = 10
x = np.arange(N)
y = np.array([i*(10**-38) for i in x])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot the data
ax.plot(x,y)

# Get the text object
text = ax.yaxis.get_offset_text()

# Set the size.
text.set_size(30) # Overkill!

plt.show()
```

I've written the solution above using `matplotlib.pyplot` rather than `pylab` though if you absolutely *have* to use `pylab` then it can be changed (though I'd recommend you use `matplotlib.pyplot` in any case as they are [pretty much identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469336/what-is-the-difference-between-pylab-and-pyplot) you can just do a lot more with `pyplot` easier).

#### Edit

If you were to use `pylab` then the code would be:

```
pylab.plot(x, y)

ax = pylab.gca() # Gets the current axis object

text = ax.yaxis.get_offset_text() # Get the text object

text.set_size(30) # # Set the size.

pylab.show()
```

### An example plot with an (overkill!) offset text.

[image: Plot]

Comment: Fantastic thank you, I've never used pyplot before but all other commands, that I used with pylab, seem to have worked perfectly! Thank you for such a quick and thorough answer!

Comment: If you do want to use `pylab` then you can use the command `pylab.gca().yaxis.get_offset_text().set_size(30)` which will do the same job as everything I've typed above (but it looks a bit messier :))