# pyplot order of magnitude fontsize modification when using scientific ticks python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to change the fontsize of the order of magnitude  (1e**), how can I make this happen?
the snippet :

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x_values = [1000000, 2000000, 3000000]

y_values = [1, 2, 3]

plt.plot(x_values, y_values)
plt.ticklabel_format(axis="x", style="sci", scilimits=(0,0))
```

extracted from:

https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-scale-an-axis-to-scientific-notation-in-a-matplotlib-plot-in-python

the plot is in the link.

thanks for the help!

Comment: found it an answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392833/python-pylab-how-to-alter-the-size-of-the-label-specifying-the-magnitude-of-the

Comment: `useMathText=True` Try this