# Anaconda2 ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pylab

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, matplotlib, importerror

In Eclipse, I tried import "matplotlib", but it didn't work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Hunter-\Desktop\A_Cognitive\neural_network\step_function.py", 
line 2, in <module>
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pylab
```

mycode is below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
def step_funtion(x):
return np.array(x>0,dtype=np.int)
x=np.arange(-5.0,5.0,0.1)
y=step_funtion(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.ylim(-0.1,1.1)
plt.show
```

※I checked by Windows cmd "WHERE", and finally I gets result of exsist of matplotlib's file.↓
　　>WHERE /r C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2 matplotlib.* _

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\pkgs\anaconda-navigator-1.9.2-py27_0\Lib\site- 
  packages\anaconda_navigator\static\images\logos\matplotlib.png
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\pkgs\matplotlib-2.2.3-py27h263d877_0\Lib\site- 
  packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\matplotlib.pdf
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\pkgs\matplotlib-2.2.3-py27h263d877_0\Lib\site- 
  packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\matplotlib.png
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\pkgs\matplotlib-2.2.3-py27h263d877_0\Lib\site- 
  packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\matplotlib.ppm
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\pkgs\matplotlib-2.2.3-py27h263d877_0\Lib\site- 
  packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\matplotlib.svg
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\pkgs\spyder-3.3.1-py27_1\Lib\site- 
  packages\spyder\images\matplotlib.png
```

Comment: pylab is [generally discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11471777/4799172). It wouldn't surprise me if they simply removed it in the meantime.

Comment: @roganjosh No pylab still exists. It wasn't removed. It's discouraged, but many people like it, so it stays.

Comment: @helpful Can you check if you can import matplotlib alone, `import matplotlib` ? If so, what does `print(matplotlib.__version__)` give? If not, you need to install matplotlib

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  Thx 4 ur kindness.
Idk how to check whether it is or not. Is this way wrong?→ 
import os.path
print(os.path.isfile("matplotlib"))
The result was false.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Finally I checked by Windows cmd and then the file probably nothing. The result is written on my question on Top in this page↑
What should I next?

Comment: It looks like you have not installed matplotlib. Anaconda navigator should allow you to do that quite easily.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest THX. I'll try it work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: thx answer, but it also doesn't work^^;;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hunter-\Desktop\A_Cognitive\neural_network\step_function.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot

Comment: have you checked if `matplotlib` is installed?

Comment: Thx 4 ur repling. Now I'm tring it but Idk how to check its exist.
Is this way wrong?→import os.path print(os.path.isfile("matplotlib")) This result was false.

Comment: try with: `import sys` 
`print 'matplotlib' in sys.modules`

Comment: Finally I checked by Windows cmd and then the file probably nothing.
The result is written on my question on Top in this page↑

Comment: What should I next?

Comment: Maybe Eclipse Is running another python enviroment. Check if It Is the right one