# Subplot do not plot every curve

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

Could somebody help me to fix the fact that my code is correctly plotting the first curve but not the second one ? Instructions are the same though...

```
from numpy import loadtxt
from pylab import *

res_1 = loadtxt("channel_2.txt", skiprows=1)
res_2 = loadtxt("corr_channel_2.txt", skiprows=1)

plot(res_1[:, 0], res_1[:, 1])
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)  # plot original data above
plot(res_2[:, 0], res_2[:, 1])
plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)  # plot corrected data below
plt.show()
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Invert the order of plot and subplot: subplot, plot original, subplot, plot corrected

Comment: Even better, use the object oriented approach: `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1) ; ax1.plot(original) ; ax2.plot(corrected)`

Comment: Thank you to you both

Comment: You're welcome, but I'm only one…

Comment: Please don't use `pylab`. And certainly don't `import *`.  Use `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`.  See [What is the difference between pylab and pyplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469336/what-is-the-difference-between-pylab-and-pyplot#:~:text=From%20the%20documentation%2C%20the%20emphasis,underlying%20plotting%20library%20in%20matplotlib.)