# Nonlinear colormap biased by rare large values in matplotlib/seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I consider large matrices attaining values in between -1 to 1 and I wish to plot their heatmaps in python. Most values are very small, let's say around `10^{-8}` but one or two entries are close to the edges. When I try the codes [from the answers for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282368/plotting-a-2d-heatmap-with-matplotlib) I always get an image which is mostly unicolor with some points. For instance [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGwyL.png) the image is mostly red with some black points. I did try playing with `vmin=np.amin(data),vmax=np.amax(data)` but of course it does not solve the issue.  I also tried some divergent colormaps but they didn't help much.

I wonder if `matplotlib` or `seaborn` can handle such type of data and if it is possible changing the scale/colormap so it will be wider based on the frequency of values (in the photo, that would mean I want more hues of red while keeping black points).

Minimal example which yields mostly white plot:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
uniform_data = np.random.rand(1200, 1200)
uniform_data /= 10 ** 8
uniform_data[42,42] += 2
uniform_data[442,442] -= 2
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

(Note that you should import `matplotlib.pyplot` as [`pylab` is now discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469336/what-is-the-difference-between-pylab-and-pyplot).)

If your data is uniformly distributed in a small interval, you could use the minimum and maximum of that interval for the color range. You could change these limits by, say, 10% so the extreme values still get another color (or use `cmap.set_over()` and `cmap.set_under()` to give the extreme values a completely different color).

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

uniform_data = np.random.rand(1200, 1200)
uniform_data /= 10 ** 8
uniform_data[42, 42] += 2
uniform_data[442, 442] -= 2
vmin = uniform_data[np.abs(uniform_data) < 0.1].min()
vmin = vmin * 0.9 if vmin > 0 else vmin * 1.1
vmax = uniform_data[np.abs(uniform_data) < 0.1].max()
vmmax = vmax * 0.9 if vmax < 0 else vmax * 1.1
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.heatmap with custom color range]

If the values have very different orders of magnitude, you might use their logarithm to decide the color.  With positive and negative values could be drawn in separate passes:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.randn(20, 20) ** 9
pos_data = np.where(data > 0, data, np.nan)
neg_data = np.where(data < 0, data, np.nan)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.heatmap(np.log(pos_data), cmap='Blues_r', cbar=False, ax=ax)
sns.heatmap(np.log(-neg_data), cmap='Reds_r', cbar=False, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image: using the log to decide the color]