# Python matplotlib syntax, comma before equals sign

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am reading over some example code for matplotlib and I came across something I was not understanding. In line 8, what is the purpose of the comma after the word "line"?

```
from pylab import *
import time

ion()  

tstart = time.time()               # for profiling
x = arange(0,2*pi,0.01)            # x-array
line, = plot(x,sin(x))
for i in arange(1,200):
    line.set_ydata(sin(x+i/10.0))  # update the data
    draw()                         # redraw the canvas

print ('FPS:' , 200/(time.time()-tstart))
```

Comment: Please don't use `pylab`. And certainly avoid `import *` which clutters the local namespace, leading to bizarre behavior. Instead, use `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` and `import numpy as np`.  See [What is the difference between pylab and pyplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469336/what-is-the-difference-between-pylab-and-pyplot)

Answer (score 1):

It is for unpacking only the first element of a multiple-element tuple.

In this example, `plot()` returns a single-element tuple and if you saved it directly into `line` by using `line = plot(...)`, your variable `line` would have the whole tuple with one element.

Instead, by doing `line, = plot(...)`, the element itself is being "extracted" and saved into `line` instead of the entire tuple.

[Here](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-unpacking-tuple/) are some more examples.